# How can I set global validation rule in Yii2

Tags: php, inheritance, yii2

I have started with YII2 just today. I have installed it successfully and also created required Model, Controllers & views in that using CRUD.

**Now my question is as below:**

I want to create one Global Validator Rule which we can use in throughout the Models in system.

**What I have tried so far:**

For that I have created one new model file (FormValidator) in common folder and generate one custom rule method in it.

**common/model/FormValidator.php**

```
namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;

class FormValidator extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord {

}
```

Then I tried to extend this model file to my frontend model file, but it's not working.

**frontend/model/Customerprofile.php**

```
namespace frontend\models;

use Yii;
use common\models\FormValidator;    

class Customerprofile extends FormValidator{

}
```

**It's throwing the below error message:**

```
PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException

Class 'common\models\FormValidator' not found
```

What have I missed in all these processes?

Comment: you have a typo in `use common\model\FormValidator;` but `namespace common\models;`, fix it  `use common\models\FormValidator;`

Comment: @Tony: Thanks your sharp response! i have done this change but still validation is not working.

Comment: you still have the error `Class not found` ?

Comment: @Tony: No, now i can go forward and my form rendered. but now when i press submit button its not fire validation rule.

Comment: do you have any validation rules in your *FormValidator* class ? or in *Customerprofile* ? if so add them in to the question

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extend some master class for model you have to simply extend CActiveRecord and then your models will extend this masterclass.